# realloc() in a 64bit iOS device

Tags: ios, c, realloc

When I use the C function `realloc(p,size)` in my project, the code runs well in both the simulator and on an iPhone 5.

However, when the code is running on an iPhone 6 plus, some odd things happen. The contents `a` points to are changed! What's worse, the output is different every time the function runs!

Here is the test code:

```
#define LENGTH (16)

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];   

    char* a = (char*)malloc(LENGTH+1);  
    a[0] = 33;

    a[1] = -14;

    a[2] = 76;

    a[3] = -128;

    a[4] = 25;

    a[5] = 49;

    a[6] = -45;

    a[7] = 56;

    a[8] = -36;

    a[9] = 56;

    a[10] = 125;

    a[11] = 44;

    a[12] = 26;

    a[13] = 79;

    a[14] = 29;

    a[15] = 66;

    //print binary contents pointed by a, print each char in int can also see the differene

    [self printInByte:a];

    realloc(a, LENGTH);

    [self printInByte:a]



    free(a);

}

-(void) printInByte: (char*)t{

    for(int i = 0;i < LENGTH ;++i){

        for(int j = -1;j < 16;(t[i] >> ++j)& 1?printf("1"):printf("0"));

        printf(" ");

        if (i % 4 == 3) {

            printf("\n");

        }

    }

}
```

One more thing, when LENGTH is not 16, it runs well with assigning up to a[LENGTH-1].  However, if LENGTH is exactly 16, things go wrong.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest using std::vector rather than naked pointers like this to avoid this sort of issue!

Comment: @Bids The question is about C and Objective-C not C++ (or Objective-C++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `realloc` man doc:

> The realloc() function tries to change the size of the allocation
>   pointed
>        to by ptr to size, and returns ptr.  If there is not enough room to
>        enlarge the memory allocation pointed to by ptr, realloc() creates a new
>        allocation, copies as much of the old data pointed to by ptr as will fit
>        to the new allocation, frees the old allocation, and returns a pointer to
>        the allocated memory.

So, you must write: `a = realloc(a, LENGTH);` because in the case where the already allocated memory block can't be made larger, the zone will be moved to another location, and so, the adress of the zone will change. That is why `realloc` return a memory pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do:

```
a = realloc(a, LENGTH);
```

The reason is that realloc() may move the block, so you need to update your pointer to the new address:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/